# Setting cell to formula based on reference value

Tags: google-sheets

I have Column A which I want to contain one of two formulas based on whether the value in column B is below a certain number.

For example, A2 should contain Formula 1 if B2 is less than 9.99. Otherwise, it should contain Formula 2.

I've seen how to do a lookup based on a table of values, but not conditionally if the reference value is above or below a certain amount. I suppose I could create a giant table with 10,000 values from 0.01 to 99.99, but there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

Use the IF() function.

## Explanation

Assume that formula 1 is `B2*10` and formula 2 is `B2*100`. The formula to be used is

```
=IF(B2<9.99,B2*10,B2*100)
```

## References

- [IF - Google Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)